# Is there a any leftovers of an accidental “svn checkout ” to my locally svn Repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

does `svn` save some info after checkout?
steps i have made :

1. `svn checkout home/different_location_than_original_svn_folder`
2. delete this new folder because I did not want to do it in this duplicate versoin - `rm -rf home/different_location_than_original_svn_folder`

> now did i  revert the situation exactly like it was before I
>   accidentally made `svn checkout`? or should I do anything more ?

- according to this nice post http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cleanup.html  :

> Subversion doesn't track either the state or the existence of working
>   copies on the server,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVN repository stores no information about checkouts. So, removing a complete checkout-folder in your VM undo this action. Revert is used in a different context in SVN. With revert you undo all changes in your local checkout/update-location.